# writing "_" like a character

Tags: characters

I would like to write

```
\texttt{set_x}
```

where "_" is an character and not a "math instruction". But Latex recognise it like a math instruction and ask for the missing $$...How can I do?

Comment: `\_` is the usual way. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=underscore

Comment: `\texttt{set\_x}`?

Comment: `\textunderscore` works as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `\texttt{set_x}`, you could just as easily use verbatim, for example you could do `\verb¬set_x¬`. The verbatim environment and commands typeset exactly what is typed, and ignores any LaTeX commands.

The issue with using `\texttt{set\_x}` or `\texttt{set\textunderscore x}` is that the underscore will be a different font to the rest of the text.

Hope this helps!

Comment: A better encoding (e.g. `T1`) helps to get a better underscore. `OT1` is lacking the glyph, thus it is replaced by a rule.