# How to write _ in LaTeX without it complaining

Tags: math-mode, text-mode

How can I write _ in LaTeX without it trying to force me to use math mode, which I do not want to use, as it will (after compilation) not display an _.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Will you ever be using `_`in math mode?

Comment: `\_`  as seen in the short introduction to LaTeX.

Comment: Perhaps http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48632/underscores-in-words-text?

Comment: Related/duplucate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48632/ and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38718/ and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168423/ and probably orhers

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6):

If you're absolutely certain that you'll never need to use `_` in math mode -- where it serves to initiate a subscript term -- you could proceed by changing the character's category code to "12" ("other").

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\catcode`\_=12 % change catcode of "_" to "other" (no. 12)

\begin{document}
a_long_string_with_lots_of_underscore_characters
\end{document}
```